# Highlighting of Swift syntax in vim

Tags: vim

I want vim to highlight Swift syntax. The following is what I did. Firstly, I downloaded the Swift Language Repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/keith/swift.vim
```

to

```
~/.vim/bundle/
```

Then I added the following line to my *.vimrc* file:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/swift.vim
```

I tried to add path to *swift.vim* like this in *.vimrc*

```
Plugin '~/.vim/bundle/swift.vim'
```

But it does not work. So, question:

How to make vim highlight Swift code properly?

NOTE: I also use **YouCompleteMe** plugin.

Answer (score 1):

That `'runtimepath'` modification looks right to me. If you have `:filetype on` in your `~/.vimrc`, it should load the filetype detection from `~/.vim/bundle/swift.vim/ftdetect/swift.vim`. You can check `:scriptnames` output for it.

To manually enable Swift syntax, `:setfiletype swift` should do it.

The `Plugin` command requires the corresponding plugin manager. As you've manually cloned the Git repository already, this is not necessary. It basically performs the same `'runtimepath'` manipulations, and often also checks for plugin updates for you.